# Validação de campos javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como poderia validar um campo utilizando `document.getElementById` e ao clicar no botão por exemplo "enviar" apareça um alerta informando?

Answer (score 1):

Com javascript puro crie uma função e chame ela no `onsubmit()` como argumento é passado o form com todos os seus campos, então é possível validar eles dessa forma `form.campo.value`

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validar(form){
    if(!form.nome.value){
        alert('informe o nome');
    }else{
        form.submit();  
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="validar(this);return false;">
      <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="submit" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar o event.preventDefault() para parar a submissão dos dados.

```
<script>

var form = document.getElementById("formulario");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;

    if(nome == ""){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Por favor preencha o nome");
        return false;
    }

});

</script>
<body>

<form name="teste" id="formulario">
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome"  />
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```